# the javascript result array only print last XML line even though I use 0

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I have subtitle XML file that had start, dur, and text to assign temporay array then pass to Subtitle array each index. When I want to see Subtitle array with 0 index, it should print first text line included start, dur, and text but instead it print the last text line.
The wrong result show,

467.071,3.643, Thanks for watching, please subscribe, rate and comment

I tried index 50 and it still print the last line. Does I add it in wrong loop or what?

Here is sample of first 3 lines of XML(total text lines is 136),

```
<transcript>
<text start="2.014" dur="1.276">Greetings fellow nerds.</text>
<text start="3.291" dur="3.446">In this video we&#39;re going to make glow sticks of various colors</text>
<text start="6.738" dur="2.277">and explain a few interesting points about them.</text>
</transcript>
```

here a javascript example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function loadXMLDoc(dname)
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
                xhttp.send();

                return xhttp.responseXML;
            }

            function init()
            {
                var subtitleArray = new Array();
                var tempArray = new Array();
                var c = document.getElementById('container');

                captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
                x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

                for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                {
                    tempArray[0] = x[i].getAttribute('start');
                    tempArray[1] = x[i].getAttribute('dur');
                    tempArray[2] = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                    subtitleArray[i] = tempArray;

                }


                c.innerHTML = subtitleArray[0];
            }
            window.onload = init;
        </script>
```

Comment: Just guesses on how to fix it: initialize (and possibly also declare) `tempArray` inside the for loop and/or change `for(i=0;...)` to `for(var i=0;...)`

Comment: Got that worked. I move declare tempArray inside for loop.

Comment: In case you wanted to know why that was happening, it's because when you assign `subtitleArray[i] = tempArray;` every element of `subtitleArray` was pointing to the same object, so changing `tempArray` anywhere was changing it for all elements of `subtitleArray`. By creating a new object in each iteration of the loop, each element in `subtitleArray` is getting its own `tempArray` to work with.